# Querying xmin column in Postgres yields xid in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am trying to sequentially grab the first record that matches the greater than or equal query on the `xmin` column compared to an incrementing integer in PostgreSQL. My query looks like this at execution time:

```
SELECT xmin, column1, column2, column3 FROM records WHERE xmin >= $1 LIMIT 1 ;
```

And then at call time, I pass the args `1` to the query through the standard sql.QueryRow function.

However, I expect to be getting back a row, instead I'm returned the following error.

```
pq: operator does not exist: xid >= unknown
```

Two things here: I can't figure out where `xid` is coming from since I never query for it, and I can't figure out why the placeholder value is not being added correctly either. The argument is getting passed to the query at call time, it's not nil or anything, but the Postgres engine doesn't like my query.

Answer (score 2):

If you had `'blah' >= 4` the error would say something like `operator does not exist: text >= integer`. The `xid` is a **type** not a column. It isn't an integer and can't directly be compared to one.

You can do `xid::text::bigint >= $1` if you really want to but make sure you understand the implications of transaction wrap-around.

Let me repeat that last point - go away and read up about how PostgreSQL transaction IDs work before you start trying to compare them numerically.

Comment: I tried to compare them numerically because they were being returned as numbers. Nowhere in the Postgres documentation about the xmin column does it state that the value it returns is a text. This looks like it's exactly my problem, though. I understand OID wrap-around, it's not a problem for my use case. Thanks.